# Observation for UndoManager

Tags: java, listener, observer-pattern

I use the [UndoManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html) in my Swing application.
If `undo()`, `redo()`, `addEdit()` or other methods are called on the UndoManager, the Undo und Redo buttons eventually must be enabled or disabled.

I can't find a way to react at those method calls. There seems to be no Observer or Listener pattern implemented for this purpose.

And update the enabled property of Undo and Redo buttons every time, when UndoManager methods are called ... this can't be the best practice?!

**An example:**

- Edit > insert -- adds an Edit to the UndoManager
- Edit > cut -- adds an Edit to the UndoManager

In both cases, the Undo button must be enabled (if it is not yet).
I need a way to react at all these *changes in the UndoManager*!

Comment: Maybe there is no better way than subclass the UndoManager and add two methods: `addHistoryChangeListener(listener)` and `removeHistoryChangeListener(listener)`. The listeners will be informed whenever the list of `UndoableEdit`s changes. This way I can react, and enable or disable the Undo/Redo buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You would add the listener(s) to the undo and redo buttons.  The UndoManager has no idea what Swing components you're using to undo or redo.

Here's a [snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TheuseofUndoManager.htm) showing a button listener for an undo button.

```
// Add a listener to the undo button. It attempts to call undo() on the
// UndoManager, then enables/disables the undo/redo buttons as
// appropriate.
undoButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    try {
      manager.undo();
    } catch (CannotUndoException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      updateButtons();
    }
  }
});

  // Method to set the text and state of the undo/redo buttons.
  protected void updateButtons() {
    undoButton.setText(manager.getUndoPresentationName());
    redoButton.setText(manager.getRedoPresentationName());
    undoButton.getParent().validate();
    undoButton.setEnabled(manager.canUndo());
    redoButton.setEnabled(manager.canRedo());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks; but sorry, you misunderstood me. I'd rather like to add a Listener to the UndoManager. Because many commands in my application might influence the UndoManager in some way, that the Undo or Redo buttons must be disabled.